# Reading from text file with '/n'

Tags: c, string, printf, newline

Okay. So I'm reading and storing text from a text file into a char array, this is working as intended. However, the textfile contains numerous newline escape sequences. The problem then is that when I print out the string array with the stored text, it ignores these newline sequences and simply prints them out as "\n".

Here is my code:

```
char *strings[100];

void readAndStore(FILE *file) {
  int count = 0;
  char buffer[250];

  while(!feof(file)) {
    char *readLine = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file);
    if(readLine) {
      strings[count] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
      strcpy(strings[count], buffer);
      ++count;
    }

  }
}

int main() {

  FILE *file1 = fopen("txts", "r");
  readAndStore(&*file1);
  printf("%s\n", strings[0]);
  printf("%s\n", strings[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output becomes something like this:

> Lots of text here \n More text that should be on a new line, but isn't \n And so \n on and 
>   and on \n

Is there any way to make it read the "\n" as actual newline escape sequences or do I just need to remove them from my text file and figure out some other way to space out my text?

Comment: Apart from the mysterious global we can only assume is a `char *[]` ptr array, you realize that in the event of a read error you blindly increment `count` regardless and thus leave one slot in your string pack in the dust in the process, right? And if your text file actually contains a backslash *character* followed by an `n` (*two* characters), don't expect `fgets` to magically translate that for you. It won't.

Comment: Moreover you don't check whether `fopen` succeeded. If it returns `NULL` (say because the file is not there), you have undefined behavior later when you try to use `file1`.

Comment: It would make more sense just to store the file with actual newlines in the file, rather than escape sequences. The escape sequences only make sense for strings in the code, where the compiler converts them.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, I wasn't aware of that, no need to be snarky about it.

Comment: @Baldrick All right, I'd need to do it in some other way than fgets then presumably since I want each "section" stored together, regardless of how many lines its on.

Comment: @Baldrick there may be a perfectly valid reason why Hallow has it stored this way. It could be required that no *real* newlines are present in whatever mechanism it is being used, and now he just needs them turned back into their former selves. I've seen similar. Its not *common*, but it is certainly not unheard of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Fact is that `\n` is a special escape sequence for your compiler, which turns it into a single character literal, namely "LF" (line feed, return), having ASCII code `0x0A`. So, it's the *compiler* which gives a special meaning to that sequence.

Instead, when reading from file, `\n` is read as two distinct character, ASCII codes `0x5c,0x6e`.

You will need to write a routine which replaces all occurences of `\\n` (the string composed by characters \ and n, the double escape is necessary to tell the compiler not to interpret it as an escape sequence) with `\n` (the single escape sequence, meaning new line).

Comment: +1. Its too damn late for me to be commenting on code. Nice writeup.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response Stefano :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only intend to replace '\n' by the actual character, use a custom replacement function like

```
void replacenewlines(char * str)
{
   while(*str)
   {
      if (*str == '\\' && *(str+1) == 'n') //found \n in the string. Warning, \\n will be replaced also.
      {
         *str = '\n'; //this is one character to replace two characters
         memmove(str, str+1, strlen(str)); //So we need to move the rest of the string leftwards
               //Note memmove instead of memcpy/strcpy. Note that '\0' will be moved as well
      }
      ++str;
   }
}
```

This code is not tested, but the general idea must be clear. It is not the only way to replace the string, you may use your own or find some other solution.

If you intend to replace all special characters, it might be better to lookup some existing implementation or sanitize the string and pass it as the `format` parameter to `printf`. As the very minimum you will need to duplicate all '%' signs in the string.

Do **not** pass the string as the first argument of `printf` as is, that would cause all kinds of funny stuff.

Comment: Hopefully there aren't many of those in the string, because repeatedly moving current-location through tail is *expensive* (not like that `strlen()` is cheap either). A single traversal with two char ptrs (one read-point, one write-point) requires neither. but the idea is sound regardless, so +1.